# How to solve 'Spider_error_processing_headers' problem while using Scrapy's CrawlSpider and LinkExtractor?

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy, pagination, header

I got a massage lik ERROR: Spider error processing and line 276, in aiter_errback
yield await it.**anext**() in my terminal, and my code given below
Can anyone tell me where is the problem.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class CandywareCrawlspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "candyware_crawlspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.candywarehouse.com"]
    # start_urls = ["https://www.candywarehouse.com/collections/wedding?page=24"]

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'

    # Editing the user-agent in the request sent
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.candywarehouse.com/collections/wedding?page=24', headers={
            'user-agent': self.user_agent
        })

    # Setting rules for the crawler
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@class="pagination-custom"]//li/a[@title="Next »"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='set_user_agent'),)
    #
    # # Setting the user-agent
    def set_user_agent(self, request, spider):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):

        product_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="js-grid"]/div')

        for product in product_list:
            product_name = product.xpath('.//p[@class="product__grid__title"]/text()').get().strip()
            price = product.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()').get().strip()
            review_counts = product.xpath('.//span[@class="tt-product-block__rating"]/text()').get().replace('\n', '').replace('   ', '')

            yield {
                'product_name': product_name,
                'price': price,
                'review_counts': review_counts,
                'User-Agent': response.request.headers['User-Agent'],
            }
```

Comment: See my answer, I only got this error and after fixing it I didn't get another one. If you're still having problems then please update your code and paste the complete error.

Comment: It would help if you posted the full error code and traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) on the result from `get()` function you need to make sure you're getting a string.

```py
product_name = product.xpath('.//p[@class="product__grid__title"]/text()').get(default='').strip()
price = product.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()').get(default='').strip()
review_counts = product.xpath('.//span[@class="tt-product-block__rating"]/text()').get(default='').replace('\n', '').replace('   ', '')
```